# Map centering issue in SafeCracker form with Google Maps for EE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-for-ee

I'm using Google Maps for EE in a SafeCracker form, and the map field is within some jQuery tabs. I previously had an issue with the map not displaying correctly if it wasn't on the first tab that loaded when the page loads ([as per this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/google-maps-for-ee-field-not-displaying-correctly-in-a-jquery-tabbed-form)), but this has been solved by calling the tabs with the following code in my external functions.js file:

```
$('.tabbed-form .tabs').kosTabs({
  after: function() {
    if(typeof Gmap !== 'undefined') {
      var instance = Gmap.instances[0];
      if(typeof instance !== 'undefined') {
        google.maps.event.trigger(instance.map, 'resize');
        instance.map.setCenter(instance.center);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The above solution works fine for creating new entries as the map centres on the latitude, longitude and zoom that I specified in the custom field settings.

But when editing an existing entry that has already had a marker plotted on the map though, I'm finding that the map isn't loading with the marker in view on the map (like it would do in normal circumstances) - instead, it's loading at the map centre (the one entered in the custom field settings), but at a zoomed-in level.

Can anyone show me how to adapt the above JS to make existing entries load with the marker in view please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before issuing the resize call, simply record the current map centre so you can reset it. Like this:

```
$('.tabbed-form .tabs').kosTabs({
  after: function() {
    if(typeof Gmap !== 'undefined') {
      var instance = Gmap.instances[0];
      if(typeof instance !== 'undefined') {
        var center = instance.map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(instance.map, 'resize');
        instance.map.setCenter(center);
      }
    }
  }
});
```